# how to select n first characters from first column according to the number of the second column

Tags: text-processing

During my workflow I have created this file:

```
AAGGAGGGAGCTGCATGGAACCTGTGGATATATACACACAAGGTTAACCTCTGTCCTGTAAA  8  
GGAGTTCAGATGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTGGAGGTCTCTGCTGGGGCCACCCTGTCCTCTCAG  30     
GAGAGAGGAAAGGAAGCGATTGCAGAACTTTCCACAAGGCTTTAGATTCCCCTGTCACAGAG  15  
GGAGGAGAAAGAATCAACTTTATAGCATCAGCCCCTTGTTTATTTTAAGTTCAGGGTTTAAG  13  
GGGAGAACATTTCCCTCCTTGTCCTCTCCTATCTCACTTACTACATTCCCACTGGTCACTGT  7  
GGGACATTTGTGATTACATGGTTGCAGTATTCTTTTTGTTCTTAGTCAGACTGTATAATTGG  4
```

I would like to select from each text of the first column the first number of letters as present in the amount of the second column. Like first 8 character of the first row, first 30 character of the second row etc..

Like the first as example the output would be something like this:

```
AAGGAGGG  
GGAGTTCAGATGTGTGCTCTTCCGATCTGG
```

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ $0 = substr($1, 0, $2) } 1' file.txt
```

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.* ([0-9]+).*/s!^(.{\1}).*!\\1!/' file.txt | \
    cat -n | \
    sed -r -f - file.txt
```

(GNU `sed` because it can read script files from `stdin`).

With `perl`:

```
perl -lpe 's/.*?([ACTG]+)\s+(\d+).*/ substr($1, 0, $2)/e' file.txt
```

Another way with `perl`:

```
perl -lape '$_ = substr($F[0], 0, $F[1])' file.txt
```

Comment: `awk '{ print substr($1, 0, $2) }'`.  No side effect on `$0` or cryptic `1` pattern with implicit `print` action.

Comment: Also, this: `awk '$0 = substr($1, 0, $2)'`.

Comment: @kaz: Re: cryptic `1`: you must be new here...

Answer (score 1):

Without sed:

```
while read -r d n;do echo ${d:0:$n};done < file.txt
```

Comment: Downvoted for [using `echo`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/135943) of [unquoted variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/135943) in a [shell loop to process text](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943).